# plotly cannot import name exceptions

Tags: python, plotly

I know this question has been asked before but *there are very few solutions given and I don't understand the ones that are provided*.

I'm trying to import my module packages and I receive the error below. The strange thing is this was all working 2 days ago and I haven't really done anything since with it so I can't understand why this is now appearing.

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd
import math as m
pyo.offline.init_notebook_mode()
```

this returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f7b4615963aa> in <module>()
----> 1 import plotly.offline as pyo
      2 from plotly.graph_objs import *
      3 from plotly import tools
      4 import plotly.plotly as py
      5 import pandas as pd

C:\Users\Lewis\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\__init__.py in <module>()
      8 
      9 """
---> 10 from . plotly import (
     11     sign_in,
     12     update_plot_options,

C:\Users\Lewis\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py in <module>()
     28 from requests.compat import json as _json
     29 
---> 30 from plotly import exceptions, files, session, tools, utils
     31 from plotly.api import v1, v2
     32 from plotly.plotly import chunked_requests

ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptions'
```

I've tried updating Plotly but this didn't do anything either. Could this be because I installed Jupyter notebook with my Anaconda installation, and my Lib\site-packages directory is within the Anaconda3 dir? Can't imagine this would be the cause but I can't think of much else. Any ideas?

[edit]

```
import sys

sys.path

['',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\plotly',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\.ipython']
```

Comment: It worked for me in both python2 and python3. Could you post your `sys.path` ? Also have you tried it in a fresh Anaconda env?

Comment: Thanks for the taking a look. I've updated my initial post to include the sys.path. I'm not sure what you mean by trying it in a fresh anaconda environment..

Answer (score 5):

in my case, after doing the upgrade like @Max above suggested, restarting the kernel finally fixed the problem

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install --upgrade plotly
```

run the above command. it will work